# Converting TripleDes algorithm

Tags: java, c#, encryption, tripledes

I want to convert following C# to java code, so we can decrypt old messages and encrypt new ones in java.

```
public class encryptionUtil
  {
    private TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TripleDes;
    private UTF8Encoding utfEncoding;
    private byte[] key;
    private byte[] iv;
    private string sysKey;
    private string sysUser;

    public encryptionUtil()
    {
      this.TripleDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
      this.utfEncoding = new UTF8Encoding();
      this.key = this.utfEncoding.GetBytes("123456789012345678901234");
      this.iv = this.utfEncoding.GetBytes("12345678");
      this.sysKey = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
      this.sysUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value;
    }

    public string EncryptData(string plaintext)
    {
      string str;
      try
      {
        plaintext = plaintext +  this.sysUser;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream) memoryStream, this.TripleDes.CreateEncryptor(this.key, this.iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        str = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        ProjectData.SetProjectError(ex);
        str =  plaintext ;
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
      }
      return str;
    }

    public string DecryptData(string encryptedtext)
    {

      string str;
      try
      {
        byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedtext);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream) memoryStream, this.TripleDes.CreateDecryptor(this.key, this.iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        string[] strArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        str = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.CompareString(strArray[1], this.token, false) != 0 ? "" : strArray[0];
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        ProjectData.SetProjectError(ex);
        str = "";
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
      }
      return str;
    }
```

Encryption output in c# for "Encrypt this in java"

7UlYtjB6Nls4Q3Ac4VzdY2k6hVRa1Eqjyt2ZG4818WxLCwFhx1fEeTCvOStTylyMM5ucL4DmF1NKBRga44Yqrj89VHRKZuWnFC24jMkSxucZkB3niLa7WOT4GKlii7716w6TC9iJGYLhy8mY1kqwaw==

Java code written so far, how to proceed further so that I get same result as above?

```
package com.mycompany.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

public class EncryptionUtil {

    private static SecretKey sharedkey;
    private static byte [] sharedvector;

    static {
        int keySize = 168;
        int ivSize = 8;
        try {
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
            keyGenerator.init(keySize);
            sharedkey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

            sharedvector = new byte [ivSize];
            byte [] data = sharedkey.getEncoded();

            int half = ivSize / 2;
            System.arraycopy(data, data.length-half, sharedvector, 0, half);
            System.arraycopy(sharedvector, 0, sharedvector, half, half);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        String plainText = "Encrypt this in java";
        String systemId= "949367136-5890454";

        String dataText = plainText+systemId
        String keyString = "key1234";
        String ivString  = "iv1234";

        try {
            byte[] keyBytes = keyString.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] ivBytes = ivString.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] dataBytes = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println("key="+keyBytes.toString());
            System.out.println("iv="+ivBytes.toString());
            System.out.println("plaintextBytesUTF-8="+dataBytes.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String Encrypt(String val) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sharedkey, new IvParameterSpec(sharedvector));

        return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(cipher.doFinal(val.getBytes()));
    }

    public static String Decrypt(String val) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sharedkey, new IvParameterSpec(sharedvector));

        return new String(cipher.doFinal(new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(val)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Encrypt new messages using tripledes? You could just as well leave them unencrypted

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: TripleDES is completely outdated

Comment: See this thread: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/security-comparsion-of-3des-and-aes

Comment: You mean DES? "Neither 3DES or AES is breakable with current technology "

Comment: @cFrozenDeath: While 3DES is starting to get up there in age, it's not considered currently breakable with current technology. It's pretty low in my list of "encryption methods I would support", however, because it will probably end up being breakable well before AES will.

Comment: @willaien not only that, but also AES is known to perform faster. Regarding to this question itself, OP, do you know how to transform the WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() to Java?

Comment: Don't  know how to get  WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value in java. But following command can give me value in windows shell                         "wmic useraccount get name,sid"

Comment: Both the key and iv are to short so either there will be some non-standard padding of junk  bytes will be used to bring them up to the required lengths.

Comment: Debug: Add some hex dumps of the inputs and outputs as close t the encryption/decryption calls as possible for both the C# and Java examples. Use fulllength key (24-bytes) and iv (8-bytes). Note: the 3DES key length is 168-bits but 24-bytes, only 7-bits are used per byte.

Comment: Fixed key and iv length to 24 and 8 sizes

Comment: Got it converted after comparing console output at each step